# How to use std::lock_guard on a class member mutex

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex

In the following code the `bad` method fails to compile, but the `good` method does not. Why is providing the explicit reference to `this` making a difference here?

```
#include <mutex>

class Foo
{
 private:
  std::mutex lock_;

 public:
  Foo() = default;
  ~Foo() = default;

  void bad();
  void good();
};

void Foo::bad()
{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(lock_);
}

void Foo::good()
{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(this->lock_);
}

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

compile error:

```
test.cpp: In member function ‘void Foo::bad()’:
test.cpp:18:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::lock_guard<std::mutex>::lock_guard()’
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(lock_);
```

You can play with the [ideone](https://ideone.com/qfflMw) if you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an instance of the most vexing parse. The parentheses here don't do what you think they do. This:

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(lock_);
```

is equivalent to:

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_;
```

which should make it clear why what you're trying to do won't compile, and why you're getting the compile error you're getting. What you need to do is provide a name for the `lock_guard`:

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _(lock_);
```

The good version works because the `this->` qualification prevents the name from being able to be treated as an identifier.

---

Note: `lock_` is a `std::mutex` and not any kind of lock, which makes it a very confusing name. You should name it something more reflective of what it is. Like `mutex_`.

Comment: Why does it compile when this-> is introduced?

Comment: @Borgleader Because it can no longer be parsed as an identifier - so it cannot be ambiguously treated as a declaration.

Comment: Just a side note - the second variant while compiles, does not really lock anything for any meanigful time - lock expires immediately after this line, and not at the end of the function, which was probably desired.

Answer (score 5):

If you declare your lock_guard correctly, they both work:

```
void Foo::bad()
{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> x{lock_};
}

void Foo::good()
{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> y{this->lock_};
}
```

Using a temporary is almost useless, because the lock gets released immediately.  Correct usage is to declare a local variable with automatic lifetime.

Answer (score 4):

You need to actually create a variable, for example

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(lock_);
```